# solving inequality with minimum value in 3 dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Some context for this question, i took it from the chinese gao kao exam but it was translated word for word.

The answer is said to be -5 or 3 for a. If anyone can give some insights into the process to reaching the solution that would be amazing

if:

```
x + y >= a
x - y <= -1
```

and:

```
minimum value of z = x + ay = 7
```

What is a?

Im confused as to what the question means by the minimum value oz z, surely z is a plane in 3D, how can it have a minimum value? Unless its gradient along x and y is 0, how could it have a minimum value?

Comment: What is the minimum problem? It seems ambiguous. What expression are computing the minimum of? What are the constraints? The triple equality $z = x + ay = 7$ is very confusing.

Comment: Im afraid i dont know, just took the question from gao kao chinese exam but it was translated online. I copied word for word the translated question

Comment: Fair enough, but without that clarifying information, this question is impossible to answer. So, for that reason, I'm voting to close it. Good luck with it.

Comment: Why are you voting to close the question just because you believe there is insufficient information. Insufficient information is relative to yourself only. Others may have solved similar problems, so stop being selfishg and answer other questions

Comment: I voted, because it's sort of the way the site works. If you think a question cannot be adequately answered in its current form, you're supposed to vote to close it. Questions that can be salvaged can be edited, and such questions can be re-opened (or, if salvaged in time, they will not get enough votes to be closed in the first place). It seems that mvw has found a plausible interpretation of your question, but it's ultimately your responsibility to clearly communicate your question.

Comment: I think what your question is missing is just proper formatting. See the [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a guide to formatting mathematics on this site. If you want to see how mvw has formatted their answer (so you can copy and adapt their code), you can press "edit" to see how they've done it. Normally, for a new user (which you aren't technically any more), I would format for them, but only if I understood what they were trying to convey, which is certainly not the case here.

Comment: Tech  Please read [How to ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|130.7054) and edit your post to improve it.  you failed to include sufficient context. Please don't pull "relativism" to tell users off.  Theo should be credited for explaining, straight-up, why he was voting to close.  If you tell experienced users that their thoughts are merely opinions, they'll learn to stop giving you any reason why.  The fate of this post is in your hands.

Comment: It is relative, whether he knows how to solve the problem of not is relative to his own experience. Not everyone is brilliant, voting to close a question because you yourself cannot answer it is well selfish and stupid. If science were that way, what do you think would happen?

Comment: @TechVisionary Can you provide a link to the original question and/or its translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea:
This can be formulated as a [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem.

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & c^\top u \\
w.r.t. & A u \le b
\end{array}
$$
with
$$
c = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
a
\end{pmatrix}
, 
u = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
,
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} 
,
b = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-a \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If one can formulate the solution in terms of $a$ then it should be possible to select $a$ such that the minimum is $7$.

Having two variables $x$ and $y$ one can attempt to solve this graphically.

[image]

The first inequality $-x - y \le -a$ is solved by points from the half space on and above the line
$$
y = -x + a
$$
This region is rendered in magenta colour in the image above.

The second inequality $x - y \le -1$ is solved by points from the half space on and above the line
$$
y = x + 1
$$
This region of the plane is rendered in light blue colour in the image above.

The feasible region, where the variables $u=(x, y)$ fulfill the constraints $A u \le b$, is the intersection of the two half planes, rendered in purple colour.

The points which satisfy the cost function $c^\top u = z$ form a line, the image shows the cost function $c^\top u = x + ay = 7$.
For this particular value of $a = 4$ it does not have a point with the feasible region in common.

The minimum seems to be on the edge of the feasible region where both lines intersect ([Optimal Vertices ..](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Optimal_vertices_(and_rays)_of_polyhedra)):
$$
\begin{align}
y = -x + a &= x + 1 \iff \\
a &= 2x + 1 \iff \\
x &= \frac{a - 1}{2} \Rightarrow \\
y &= \frac{a + 1}{2}
\end{align}
$$
That edge $P = ((a-1)/2, (a+1)/2)$ should also lie on the line of the cost function:
$$
x + a y = 7
$$
Thus we get a quadratic equation in $a$:
\begin{align}
\frac{a - 1}{2} + a \frac{a + 1}{2} &= 7 \iff \\
(a - 1) + a (a + 1) &= 14 \iff \\
a^2 + 2a + 1 &= 16 \iff \\
(a + 1)^2 &= 16 \iff \\
a &= \pm 4 - 1 \in \{ -5, 3 \}
\end{align}
This should be roughly the solution. The reasoning for the minimum lying at that edge might be improved, but sorry it is late. :-)

Here are the images for the found $a$ values:

[image: a = 3]

[image: a = -5]

Comment: Thank you, have upvoted

Comment: No, you did not upvote, @Tech.

Comment: @amWhy did you downvote my answer?

Comment: @TechVisionary I added some images to help understanding my solution proposal.